# Objects added to JPanel not showing up

Tags: java, swing

I will be using CardLayout in the future, so I am making each "page" its own panel. I made this whole panel in the code below but I just get a blank JFrame.

Class for the panel:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class ECLoginPanel extends ECFrame {
    public static JPanel LoginPanel;
    public JButton login;
    public JButton signup;
    
    public ECLoginPanel() {
        JPanel loginPanel = new JPanel();
        loginPanel.setBackground(darkblue);
        
        login = new JButton("Login");
        signup = new JButton("Signup");
        
        login.setBackground(lightblue);
        login.setFocusPainted(false);
        login.setBorder(emptyBorder);

        signup.setBackground(lightblue);    
        signup.setFocusPainted(false);
        signup.setBorder(emptyBorder);
            
        loginPanel.add(login);
        loginPanel.add(signup);
        
        frame.add(loginPanel);
        
    }
    
}
```

Class for the JFrame:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class ECFrame {
    JFrame frame;
    public ECFrame() {
        frame = new JFrame("EasyChat");
        frame.setSize(800,450);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
public class ECMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ECLoginPanel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Netbeans section.  Start from the beginning of the tutorial and follow Oracle's example code.

Comment: I've looked at this a bit, and I just haven't been able to find very much about panels/cardlayout but I'll look again.

Comment: *I just haven't been able to find very much about panels/cardlayout* - not sure what that comment means there is a complete section on `How to Use CardLayout` which contains a complete working example that will show you how to better structure your code. Start with the working example and modify as required. Also, variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Again, follow the example code which will use Java naming conventions.

Comment: *"The first thing you might think is that I have no JFrame created"* Yeah, nah. The first thing I thought is 'add a [mre]'. Then I'd look at this in more detail. In the meantime, I am voting to close.

Comment: Thinking about it, yeah, this really isn't a great question, and it's very unclear. I think I'm just gonna keep adding to my project and read Oracle's Swing tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

The good news is your problem isn't in Swing and the solution is simple. You are creating a new ECFrame (the superclass) in your main, not the login panel you really want.

In your main class try creating new ECLogin, not ECFrame:

```
public class ECMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ECLoginPanel();
    }
}
```

Comment: (1-) That is not the solution. You can't just create a panel and make it visible. The ECPanel should NOT extend ECFrame. In fact you should not even have an ECFrame class. The entire design of these classes are wrong which is why the OP needs to read the Swing tutorial for a solution which will include a better design of the classes involved.

Comment: That is the solution for the question, @camickr. The solution is tested and works. I'm not trying to force another person to write perfect code. You might have issues with his design, but that is not his question. The fact is, the solution I wrote solves the issue he has. I've run the code myself and it works. Don't gatekeep.

Comment: No it it not the question because the OP doesn't know it is a design issue or they would not code the classes that way. The problem is if you keep designing code like this you will continue to have problems which are complicated by poor design issues. If you take a couple of minutes now you will fix these issues which will result if fewer problems going forward. What does the OP do when they want to add another panel to the frame? Based on the current design it would also need to extend ECFrame which would result in two frames being created.

Comment: The OP wrote that this is not the final form for the code. They are clearly stuck with a blank JFrame and don't understand why.  I'm not saying it's great code, but downvoting a working solution makes not sense. It doesn't help. The OP was not asking for a perfect design (in your eyes). They are stuck with a blank screen and my solution solves that. They can use it and move on to using CardLayout.

Comment: *They are clearly stuck with a blank JFrame* - exactly. And the solution is not to have a panel class extend another class where the frame is created. It is a poor design and will need to be fixed for the next step of creating multiple panels to be used in the CardLayout. If you don't have a 'reasonable" design of classes you can't keep building on top of it. The downvote was because you made no mention of this and to discourage anybody else from reading this answer to use it as a solution.

Comment: Understood.  Thanks for the explanation.